# What is the stem/seatpost thing on the Bicymple?

Tags: seatpost

Anybody know if that's a pre-existing part that's been repurposed or if it's something that they've had custom fabricated?

[image: Bicymple Side View]

There are more pictures on their [kickstarter page](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/joshbechtel/the-bicymple?ref=live).

Comment: I think it's known as an "abomination".

Comment: It just looks like the only design possible to get the seat as far awar as possible from the handlebars.

Comment: Edited the link to their kickstarter page, since the website link appears to be down.

Comment: It hurts to watch this movie IN SO MANY WAYS!!!!! I feel outraged! (about the movie in the linked page)

Comment: ... 180mm Travel shocks, national down hill circuit here we come......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a stem, which has had the bar mount replaced with  a seatpost clamp.  It is a custom part for this frame design, only.  They are having it fabbed.